# Send Image Generated by Biokit library as a post response using Flask

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask, flask-restful

I am currently implementing a Flask restful web service. Basically, a user submits a JSON which contains data in a POST body. I receive the JSON payload in the POST body, and then run my analytic (in this case I am performing correlation). I generating a correlation matrix. Using the Biokit library, the correlation matrix can be converted into an image shown in this link :

http://thomas-cokelaer.info/blog/2014/10/corrplot-function-in-python/

I want to return this image back to the user as a response. I have tried code similar to the following links:

https://gist.github.com/rduplain/1641344

and

https://gist.github.com/wilsaj/862153/119c6fc8ba2b0f3ffcd285a6852acb028660395b

a sample of my code is below:

```
#c.plot function generates the image that i want to send
#c.plot function comes from biokit library

fig = Figure(c.plot(colorbar=True,method='circle', shrink=.8, 
upper='circle'))

canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)

png_output = StringIO.StringIO()

canvas.print_png(png_output)

resp = make_response(png_output.getvalue())

resp.headers['Content-Type']='image/png'

resp.status_code = 200

return resp
```

When I run my flask app, it shows that something is being sent back as a response, however, I am not sure what it is. The content length is smaller than my actual image size in bytes.

As in the two links, they use `ax = fig.subplot(111)`, and set the axes and such, however, my plot isn't a simple plot that is `x` vs `y`, and I cannot just get the `x` values and `y` values from the plot and plot them against each other.

Any help would be greatly appreciated